# Introspect the types returned from a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I introspect the types returned from a SQL query. I can introspect the table to get the columns and types, but during run time, there may be fields that are not in the db (for example, the `concat` method). Here is an example:

```sql
SELECT id, email, number_of_logins, concat(first_name, last_name) as full_name from users
```

Is there a way to find the types?

Comment: `pg_typeof(concat(first_name, last_name))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check using `pg_catalog.format_type(concat(first_name, last_name))` also try `pg_typeof(col)`

```
SELECT id, email, number_of_logins, pg_catalog.format_type(concat(first_name, last_name)) as full_name from users
```

Comment: Is it possible to run the query AND get the data types at the same time? Feels like I have to run it twice to get it here?

Comment: `concat(first_name, last_name) as full_name, pg_typeof(concat(first_name, last_name)) AS concat_type`

Answer (score 1):

With recent versions of `psql`, you can simply use `\gdesc` rather than `;` to end your query:

```
SELECT 42 AS x \gdesc 

 Column |  Type   
--------+---------
 x      | integer
(1 row)
```